# Change only one element in list to float or other transformation

Tags: python, string, list, casting, floating-point

Let say I have this data:

```
[[u'alpha',u'0.1'],[u'bravo',u'0.2']]
```

What I want to achieve is to change the 2nd element for each item to float

Here is my code. It able to get the output that I want, but I'm looking for something simpler, and more generic. For example, the element might be 99th out of 100, or I want to change the first element to title case.

I'm exploring map and lambda but cannot see how to use it in this case.

```
#!/bin/env python

data = [[u'alpha',u'0.1'],[u'bravo',u'0.2']]

print data

tgb=[]
for item in data:
    rfv=[]
    for x,elem in enumerate(item):
            if x == 1:
                    rfv.append(float(elem))
            else:
                    rfv.append(elem)
    tgb.append(rfv)

print tgb
```

Output:

```
[[u'alpha', u'0.1'], [u'bravo', u'0.2']]
[[u'alpha', 0.1], [u'bravo', 0.2]]
```

Comment: Why are you iterating if you know which element you want to change?

Comment: What other option than iterating the element?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams care to share example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do the following:

```
def convert(x):
    try:
        return float(x)
    except ValueError, e:
        return x.title()

data = [[u'alpha',u'0.1'], [u'bravo',u'0.2'], [u'charlie', u'0.1', u'0.2', u'0.3', u'0.4']]
data = [[convert(element) for element in entry] for entry in data]

print data
```

This will attempt to convert all items to floats, but leave them as strings if they cannot be converted in title format. This would display the following output:

```
[[u'Alpha', 0.1], [u'Bravo', 0.2], [u'Charlie', 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4]]
```

This would also work for 100 elements. Note, it would not be possible to use a lambda for the `convert()` function as it would need to be a single expression.

Alternatively, `map()` could be used to give the same results:

```
data = [map(convert, entry) for entry in data]
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's solve with **map**, **lambda** and **slicing** as you mentioned in your question. If you know at which **index** you want to modify, you can do:

```
print map(lambda x,index=1:x[:index]+[float(x[index])]+x[index+1:] ,s)
```

Note that, I have used 1 as default value of **index**.

Demo:

```
>>s=[[u'alpha',u'0.1',u'0.1'],[u'bravo',u'0.2',u'0.1',u'0.1']]
>>print map(lambda x,index=1 : x[:index] + [float(x[index])] + x[index+1:] , s)
[[u'alpha', 0.1, u'0.1'], [u'bravo', 0.2, u'0.1', u'0.1']]
```

Comment: In future, I might have 100 element, and I'm not planning to write

data= [[i[0],i[2],i[3], ...... i[98,]float(i[99])] for i in data ]